# Passing data between fragments without newly instantiating the receiving fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, appcompatactivity

passing data between fragments is a common scenario, answered f.i. [here](http://manishkpr.webheavens.com/android-passing-data-between-fragments/). You build an interface that is implemented by the fragments' host activity. In the activity's implementation method, the receiving fragment is newly instantiated, with the new transmitted data as a Bundle.

The problem: I'd need an old instance of the receiving fragment with the new information ADDED, not a fresh instance.

I have a main activity with one fragment container. The first fragment is a form where the user must fill in some data. A certain button opens the second fragment where an item from a treeview is selected. The selection must be transmitted to a textfield in the first fragment. Of course, the entries in the first fragment can never be deleted.

I could put all the input fields' content in an interface and refill them into a new instance of firstFragment, but that seems rather stupid to me.

Is the "one-container-multiple-fragments"-pattern applicable in my case? Or should I use a second fragment container and turn the visibilty on and off?

startactivityforresult unfortunately does not apply for fragments.

Thanks a lot!

edit: This is the code of my main activity.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //init Databinding
    oBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);

    setSupportActionBar(oBinding.toolbar);

    if(oBinding.mainContainer != null){

        //are we restoring the instance state?
        if(savedInstanceState != null){
            return; //yes - do nothing 
        }

        MainFragment oMainFragment = new MainFragment();
        getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .add(oBinding.mainContainer.getId(), oMainFragment)
                .commit();
        }
    }

@Override
    public void onCatButtonClicked() {
        NewCatFragment oSubFragment = new NewCatFragment();
        getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(oBinding.mainContainer.getId(), oSubFragment)
                .addToBackStack(null)
                .commit();
    }

@Override
public void onItemSelected(String sItem) {
//here i'd like old instance qith just some new stuff
    MainFragment oMainFragment = new MainFragment();
    Bundle oBundle = new Bundle();
    oBundle.putString("ITEM", sItem);
    oMainFragment.setArguments(oBundle);
    getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(oBinding.mainContainer.getId(), oMainFragment)
            .addToBackStack(null)
            .commit();
}
```

Comment: You can instantiate the fragments once and simply replace them in the container as needed, saving the necessary data as instance variables of your activity. You don't need to intantiate the fragment each time to fill it with data, just use a setter method on an existing fragment. If you post your code I can show u an example

Comment: That sounds like the solution, just added my code. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Levi Albuquerque, I found a simple solution. I just put the fragment in a global variable and reused it - I thought I had to instantiate it always. In that instance, I was able to simply call a setter method.

```
private MainFragment oMainFragmentInstance;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //init Databinding
    oBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);

    setSupportActionBar(oBinding.toolbar);

    if(oBinding.mainContainer != null){

        //are we restoring the instance state?
        if(savedInstanceState != null){
            return; //yes - do nothing
        }

        oMainFragmentInstance = new MainFragment();
        getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .add(oBinding.mainContainer.getId(), oMainFragmentInstance)
                .commit();
    }
}

@Override
public void onCItemSelected(String sItem) {
    oMainFragmentInstance.SetCat(sItem);
    getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(oBinding.mainContainer.getId(), oMainFragmentInstance)
            .addToBackStack(null)
            .commit();
}
```

Comment: glad you figured it out :)

Answer (score 1):

Personally I don't like global variables, it's bad practice and you need each time to update them regularly in order to use them where you want.

My solution is just use findFragment of the fragment manager

```
Fragment fragment = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("yourstringtag");
```

From here you can just do:

```
fragment.getArguments().putString("existing key","newValue");
```

Comment: Thanks - findfragmentbytag seems like the more android way to retreive fragments